# Detect if PDF contains searchable text

Tags: r, pdf, web-scraping

I want to read the text of 16000 pdf files in an R dataframe. Most of the pdfs are no Problem, `pdf_text("link")` gives the right output. The problem is that some PDFS have no copyable text. With them I get a following (sample) output:

"0123145456789 20ÿ\016\017ÿ\020\021\022ÿ\023\024\020\024\025\022ÿ\026\023ÿ\027\026\016\022\020\025\030ÿ\031\026\032\033\034\030ÿÿ\035\026\036\022\025\016\026\025ÿ\035 \037\025\033\022\032ÿ !\021\032\026\024\023\r\n  ()*+ÿ-./.0012ÿ34ÿ5656ÿ7M9^.C=19ÿO=CDÿ-_`MQÿ-19GEHFC=19ÿ\.GW:CG7\r\n ()5+ÿ8.9:2ÿ;4ÿ5656ÿ7N10=@=:GÿJ1>ÿCD:ÿa>:.Cÿa01V.0ÿ<DECA1O9ÿ.9Aÿ\:K19A7\r\n ())+ÿ<:=0:>2ÿ5656ÿ7-1/=AÿY@191H=@Gbÿ̀:CC:Aÿ.9Aÿ>:.0cC=H:ÿF.F:>G7\r\n"

The solution is of course
a. Do not read out all these texts
b. Read the texts by OCR

But since this method either excludes many texts or is very time-consuming, I would like to recognize the problematic texts beforehand. Is there an easy way to do this in R?

```
text_raw<-pdf_text("link")
if(text_raw is nonsense){
text<-pdf_ocr_text(text_raw)
}else{
text<-text_raw
}
```

Comment: Did you try using `readtext()` from the **readtext** package?

Comment: Yes I did. The problem is not the code, but that the text is not in the PDF file. My goal is to detect that.

Comment: Did you try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16152583/tell-if-a-file-is-pdf-in-bash)?

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I'm not sure how to use it to distinguish between PDF with text and PDFs without text

Comment: Can you provide some examples of the pdf that have the problems?